# Volume of half-cut cylinder

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, volume

[image]

I'm having trouble obtaining the answer for this practice-test problem.

I'm taking the volume of the whole cylinder as if it weren't cut then subtract the portion cut off. But I'm not getting any of the answers below. Any hints will be greatly appreciated. Thank you all.

Comment: What is the radius of the cylinder? :)

Comment: @Linear: I'm guessing the radius must be 9. Because if not, it would have to be irrational.

Comment: Actually, we don't have to guess: A $45^\circ$ angle means that the diameter of the cylinder is the same as the height of the cut part.  (As per user113971's answer)

Comment: I had the logic of the problem correct but the radius wrong! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$d=18$ (because angle=45 degree) then $r=9$

$V=(1/2)  18 r^2 \pi + 6 r^2 \pi=1215 \pi $

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a cylinder 30cm long. Then you can slice it in half on the slant, to get two identical pieces like the one in your diagram. So what is the volume of each piece?

Comment: +1 for change from "Polish sausage" to "cylinder." :D  (of course, I gave the +1 for the validity of the answer, but still...)

Comment: @anorton: They are sold cut on the slant at my local supermarket, just like the diagram. But I realised that this might not be true for everybody.